How to update chart x-axis dynamically after initialise chart in SwiftUI iOS
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var numbers = (0..<100)
        .map { _ in Double.random(in: 0...100) }
    @State private var scrollPosition = 0
    @State var xAxisRange: ClosedRange<Int> = 0 ... 50

    var body: some View {
        Chart(Array(zip(numbers.indices, numbers)), id: \.1) { index, number in
            LineMark(
                x: .value("Index", index),
                y: .value("Number", number)
            )
        }
        .chartScrollableAxes(.horizontal)
        .chartXScale(domain: xAxisRange)
        .chartScrollTargetBehavior(
            .valueAligned(
                unit: 5,
                majorAlignment: .page
            )
        )
        .chartScrollPosition(x: $scrollPosition)
        .onChange(of: scrollPosition) {
            print(scrollPosition)
            if scrollPosition > 30 {
                xAxisRange = 0 ... 100
            }
        }
    }
}

This is sample code, I'm trying to load a dynamic data like pagination in Chart but while I'm updating the x axis scroll gets disturb and it will move far long from current data.
Whatever I am trying is this possible in SwiftUI chart?

It doesn't make sense to change the x scale while the user is scrolling along the x axis. I'd be very confused if I were the user. Why do you want to do this?

I want to load a data daily basis while user scroll left to right, so for that am calling API and appending to chart data array, in this case I am updating the x axis, so while i am updating x axis scroll is mismatching.

That still doesn't explain why you need to change the scale of the x axis. Just append new data - why do you need to do anything else after that?

lets consider i have last 2 days data, so my x-axis will be set as last 2 days, while I'm scrolling and coming to last data object, I'm fetching new last day data and appending to same array so in that case I have to update the x-axis, so if I update x axis scroll will get disturb.

You can do it via @StateObject and @Published in view model:
import SwiftUI
import Charts

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
   @Published var xAxisRange1: ClosedRange<Int> = 0 ... 50
}

struct ContentView: View {
   @State private var numbers = (0..<100).map { _ in Double.random(in: 0...100) }
   @State private var scrollPosition = 0
   @StateObject private var vm = ViewModel()

   var body: some View {
       Chart(Array(zip(numbers.indices, numbers)), id: \.1) { index, number in
        LineMark(
            x: .value("Index", index),
            y: .value("Number", number)
        )
    }
    .chartScrollableAxes(.horizontal)
    .chartXScale(domain: vm.xAxisRange1)
    .chartScrollTargetBehavior(
        .valueAligned(
            unit: 5,
            majorAlignment: .page
        )
    )
    .chartScrollPosition(x: $scrollPosition)
    .onChange(of: scrollPosition) {
        print(scrollPosition)
        if scrollPosition > 30 {
            vm.xAxisRange1 = 0 ... 100
        }
    }
}}

